# Delete matching sequential rows

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk, grep

Currently I have a csv file like this:

```
11:00 p.m.
11:00 p.m.
03:00 p.m.
03:00 p.m.
05:00 a.m.
05:00 a.m.
07:00 a.m.
12:00 p.m.
07:00 a.m.
05:00 a.m.
```

I want to delete the duplicates that are in sequential rows so the output will be this:

```
11:00 p.m.
03:00 p.m.
05:00 a.m.
07:00 a.m.
12:00 p.m.
07:00 a.m.
05:00 a.m.
```

I do not want to delete all duplicates, just duplicates that are in sequential rows, for example if the 4th and 5th row match, delete one of the duplicate rows. Is there an easy way to do this without having to run a for-loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `uniq`.

It can do what exactly you want to do.

Comment: wow this actually worked wonderfully, and it was so simple...I thought uniq deleted all duplicates?

Comment: check the man page: Filter  adjacent matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output) With no options, matching lines are merged to the first occurrence.

Comment: is there a way to do this only for the first 10 rows for example?

Answer (score 4):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '$0 != prev; {prev=$0}' file.txt
```

Comment: this worked really well as well! thanks for answering all my questions today!

Comment: @user2143205, thanks for giving me the opportunity. I learned something about `uniq` today that i did not know before  :-)

Comment: is there a way to limit the amount of lines awk checks with this command?

Comment: @user2143205, you could do this with `uniq` easily, like so - `head -10 file | uniq`